# What's wrong with this PHP statement?

Tags: php, echo

I'm new at using PHP & I'm trying to read a book called PHP 6 and MySQL 5 for Dynamic Web Sites: Visual QuickPro Guide by Larry Ullman. I'm not sure what version it is seeing as how I have the pdf version, but anyways, I'm getting this error when I run my script:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '10' (T_LNUMBER) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\IDE\comments.php on line 14

This is line 14 of my script:

```
echo '<p>This is a line of text.<br />This
is another line of text.</p>';
```

Comment: What is on the line before that?

Comment: What's the line above?

Comment: 10 # Created August 27\, 2007
11 # Created by Larry E. Ullman
12 # This script does nothing much.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the statement at all, so the error is coming from somewhere else.
Could you please edit the code in the above comment into your original post, exactly the way it looks in the script?

Comment: Well, "PHP 6" has never been released so far - trash that book.

Comment: I'm going to edit my question and add the who file

Comment: @Sven lol you beat me to it. I was about to comment on that.

Comment: You need to comment that line, get rid of the 10? ... just but `//` before the whole line

Comment: The problem is with the line above it, can you please state the line above it?

Comment: This is not the reason for the error mesage BUT - That line does not need to have a CR/LF in it. code it like this `echo '<p>This is a line of text.<br />This is another line of text.</p>';  The `<br /> creates a line break in your html, you dont need to do it in the script as well.

Comment: Okay so you haven't edited it into your post yet, but from the comment above it looks like you were trying to comment something, but that's not how you comment. Either comment /* like this */ for multiple lines or add // at the beginning of the line to comment a single line.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you copied code that has line numbers and looks like this:

```
10 # Created August 27\, 2007 11 
11 # Created by Larry E. Ullman 12 
12 # This script does nothing much. 
13
14 echo '<p>This is a line of text.<br />This is another line of text.</p>';
```

The line numbers are not part of the php and should not be copied. The code should like like so:

```
# Created August 27\, 2007 11 
# Created by Larry E. Ullman 12 
# This script does nothing much. 

echo '<p>This is a line of text.<br />This is another line of text.</p>';
```

Comment: Good guess, considering the line he says doesn't even have `10` on it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you **copied and pasted** line numbers as well as the code.

`10,11,12,...` should not be at the front of the lines.

Your code should instead look like this:

```
# Created August 27, 2007 
# Created by Larry E. Ullman
# This script does nothing much. 

echo '<p>This is a line of text.<br />This is another line of text.</p>';
```

The reason this works is because a `#` sign at the start of a line tells PHP that it is a comment and that it shouldn't read that line. **Copy and paste** is not such a good idea sometimes.